# Generating PBKDF2 Key failure

Tags: javascript, cryptography, pbkdf2

I want to generate share key with PBKDF2 algorithm, and I follows MDN's guide https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey

However, I generate an "empty" key with the following code.
Hope that someone could help me solve the problem. Thanks!

```
async function generateSecretKey() {
    const globalSalt = 'e85c53e7f119d41fd7895cdc9d7bb9dd';
    let passPhraseSalt = await hexToBuffer(globalSalt);
    let passPhraseKey = await utf8ToBuffer('password');
    let key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
                     'raw',
                     passPhraseKey, {
                         name: 'PBKDF2'
                     },
                     false,
                     ['deriveBits', 'deriveKey']
               )
    let key2 = await crypto.subtle.deriveKey({
                            "name": 'PBKDF2',
                            "salt": passPhraseSalt,
                            "iterations": 1000,
                            "hash": 'SHA-256'
                        },
                        key, {
                        "name": 'AES-CBC',
                        "length": 256
                        },
                        true,
                        ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
                )

    let key3 = await crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", key2);
    let secretKey = await bufferToHex(key3);
    return secretKey;
}

function bufferToHex(arr) {
    var i;
    var len;
    var hex = '';
    var c;

    for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        c = arr[i].toString(16);
        if (c.length < 2) {
            c = '0' + c;
        }
        hex += c;
    }
    return hex;
}
```

[The screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbp45.png)

Comment: @kelalaka i have edited it

Comment: I can only see a problem related to `await`. You use await with non-async function. though, that should give you an error.

Comment: It may be a problem and I remove it.  However, key3 still empty.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://repl.it/repls/GoldenAvariciousVerification

Comment: @Matthijs Thanks~ It also works for me. Maybe bufferToHex algorithm have some problems...